# Ajax - but only when a user has stopped typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, timer

I have a table listing with a 'notes' field in each row. I'd like to be able to update these using ajax and display a little message once they have been updated, but I'm struggling to figure out the correct code.

My plan was to capture a key press, and pass the note ID into a timer, which would be reset every time the user presses a key so it will only run once they've stopped typing for 1 second. The problem is, with multiple notes on the page I need to pass it into an array and reset the timer on each one, if this is even possible?

Here's my code:

```
    var waitTime = 1000;
    var click = false;
    var timers = new Array();

    $('.notes').keyup(function(){

        var timerVariable = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
        timerVariable = timerVariable[0];
        timerVariable = timerVariable.replace('note', '');

        timers.push(timerVariable);
        timers[timerVariable] = timerVariable;

        if(click==false){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(click==false){
                click= true;
                timerVariable = setTimeout(function(){doneTyping(id)}, waitTime);
            }
        }
    });

    $('.notes').keydown(function(){
        for (var timer in timers) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        click = false;
    });

    function doneTyping (id) {
        var staffNo = id.split("-");
        staffNo = staffNo[0];
        staffNo = staffNo.replace('note', '');

        var data = 'data='+id+'&note='+$('#'+id).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "update-notes.php", 
            type: "GET",       
            data: data,    
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                jGrowlTheme('mono', 'Updated ' + staffNo, 'Thank you, the note has been updated.', 'tick.png');
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm wondering if the problem is maybe with the way I'm calling the for loop, or something else? Any advice would be very welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a direct answer to your problem but I would personally make a jquery plugin out of your code that you would use like this:

```
$('.note-fields').myNoteAjaxPlugin({ waitFor: '1000'  });
```

Each "note field" would have it's instance of the plugin encapsulating a timer dedicated for each field. No need to worry about storing in arrays and such.

There are plenty of plugin patterns and boilerplates out there like **[this one](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate/)** and **[this other one](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/)**.

Here is a sample implementation. I've used the one boilerplate and merged it with the jquery ui bridge code (which checks for private methods, re-using a previous plugin instance or instantiating it correctly):

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = 'myNoteAjaxPlugin',
        defaults = {
            waitFor: "1000",
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {

        this.element = element;
        this.$element = $(element);

        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this._timer = null;
        this._click = false;

        this._init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype._init = function () {

        var self = this;

        this.$element.keyup(function(e){

            if( self._click === false ){
                var id = self.element.id;
                if( self._click === false ){
                    self._click = true;
                    self._timer = setTimeout(function(){self._doneTyping(id)}, self.options.waitFor);
                }
            }
        });

        this.$element.keydown(function(e) {

            if (self._timer) {
                clearTimeout(self._timer);
            }
            self._click = false;

        });

    };

    Plugin.prototype._doneTyping = function(id) {

        alert('done typing');

    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function( options ) {

        var isMethodCall = typeof options === "string",
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            returnValue = this;

        // allow multiple hashes to be passed on init
        options = !isMethodCall && args.length ?
            $.extend.apply( null, [ true, options ].concat(args) ) :
            options;

        // prevent calls to internal methods
        if ( isMethodCall && options.charAt( 0 ) === "_" ) {
            return returnValue;
        }

        if ( isMethodCall ) {
            this.each(function() {
                var instance = $.data( this, pluginName ),
                    methodValue = instance && $.isFunction( instance[options] ) ?
                        instance[ options ].apply( instance, args ) :
                        instance;

                if ( methodValue !== instance && methodValue !== undefined ) {
                    returnValue = methodValue;
                    return false;
                }
            });

        } else {
            this.each(function() {
                var instance = $.data( this, pluginName );
                if ( instance ) {
                    instance.option( options || {} )._init();
                } else {
                    $.data( this, pluginName , new Plugin( this , options) );
                }
            });
        }

        return returnValue;
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );


$('#myinput').myNoteAjaxPlugin({waitFor: '1500'});
```

**Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/2sx8w/)**

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you - I've never created a function in jQuery before so it's really useful to see the boilerplates too. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/2sx8w/) on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it:

```
var t;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search_string').keyup(function() {

        clearTimeout (t);

        t = setTimeout('start_ajax()', 3000);

    });

});

start_ajax() {

    // Do AJAX.

}
```

Comment: did you not forget to set the timeout to t there? `t = setTimeout('start_ajax()', 3000);` ???

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution but unfortunately I don't think it'll work easily with multiple timers and note fields like I have.

Comment: @ppumkin: Whoops. I did, fixed it.

Comment: @xndx: Perhaps it's better to use blur. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem could very well be with this section of code:

```
$('.notes').keyup(function(){
    var timerVariable = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
    timerVariable = timerVariable[0];
    timerVariable = timerVariable.replace('note', '');

    timers.push(timerVariable);
    timers[timerVariable] = timerVariable;

    if(click==false){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(click==false){
            click= true;
            timerVariable = setTimeout(function(){doneTyping(id)}, waitTime);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not really sure why you're doing `timers.push(timerVariable);` followed immediately by `timers[timerVariable] = timerVariable;` - they both add `timerVariable` into the array, just in (potentially?) different positions.

Also, while I know Javascript allows it, I still think changing the type of a variable is bad practice. Keep `timerVariable` as the index for your array, and create a new variable when calling `setTimeout`, rather than reusing `timerVariable`. It makes your code easier to follow, and reduces the possibility of errors being introduced.

And, finally, call `setTimeout` **then** add to your array. Your code isn't doing what you think it is - you're never actually adding the references created by your `setTimeout` calls to the array. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rn9Vt/) to see what's actually happening.

Comment: Thank you, some great suggestions and explanations here, I shall look to apply this to my code. In particular the way I defined the timer with the push function, oops!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a more streamlined version of your code:

```
$('.notes')
.each(function () {
    $(this).data("serverState", {busy: false, date: new Date(), val: $(this).val() });
})
.bind("keyup cut paste", function() {
    var note = this, $note = $(this), serverState = $note.data("serverState");

    setTimeout(function () {
        var val = $note.val();

        if ( 
            !serverState.busy
            && new Date() - serverState.date > 1000 && val != serverState.val 
        ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "update-notes.php", 
                type: "POST",       
                data: { data: note.id, note: val },
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    var staffNo = note.id.split("-")[0].replace('note', '');

                    serverState.date = new Date();
                    serverState.val  = val;
                    jGrowlTheme('mono', 'Updated ' + staffNo, 'Thank you, the note has been updated.', 'tick.png');
                },
                error: function () {
                    // handle update errors
                }, 
                complete: function () { 
                    serverState.busy = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

- Initially, the current state of each `<input>` is saved as the `serverState` in the `.data()` cache.
- Every event that can change the state of the input (i.e. keyup, cut, paste) triggers a delayed function call (1000ms).
- The function checks whether there already is a request in progress (`serverState.busy`) and backs off if there is (there is no need to hammer the server with requests).
- When it's time to send the changes to the server (1000ms after the last event) and the value actually has changed, it posts the new value to the server.
- On Ajax success it sets `serverState` to the new value, on error it doesn't. Implement error handling for yourself.

So every key press triggers the function, but only 1000ms after the last key press that actually made a change to the value change is pushed to the server.

Comment: Many thanks, this is a very good improvement on my code in many ways and I like some of the ideas, but unfortunately I have the same problem where it's running the ajax on every single key press, meaning lots of messages for the user and lots of calls to the server

Comment: @xndx: It most certainly does not. It runs the Ajax 1 second after the last keypress that made a change.